# How do I open the preferences dialog in empathy under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, menu, empathy

I run empathy (version 3.8.6) under Gnome Shell (Gnome 3.10 environment) in Ubuntu 14.04. When I open it, I get the contact page but no menu is shown. I want to open the preferences dialog but I don't see a way to get there. Where is the menu? How can I open the preferences dialog?

Comment: Try either the menu at the top bar or the icon in the bottom tray.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that there is an application-specific menu at the top bar of Gnome Shell. In fact, I deactivated the application menu in the top bar (using the TaskBar extension) as it was eating valueable space (the program name that is displayed there seems irrelevant to me) and the only menu items I've seen in the menu so far was "Quit program" (also irrelevant as the program has a close button). I didn't know and expect that genuine Gnome programs would embed their main menu there, rather than making the menu items accessible through their main window.

Comment: Glad it helped, I too was extremely confused with navigating Empathy in Gnome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application menu of Empathy doesn't sit in the window that appears when you start the application (the contact list window). Instead, it lives by default in the top panel and can be accessed by clicking on the application name ("Empathy") in the top panel (which only appears if the application has the focus).

I didn't see the menu since I deactivated this part of the top panel through the TaskBar Gnome Shell extension. I did this because seeing the current program name seemed useless to me and because I wasn't aware that a useful menu would hide there.

Now I also found that the Gnome Tweak Tool allows me to decide whether the application menu is shown in the top bar or not. In the latter case it will be integrated in the main application window.

Thanks to all for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing `prefer`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It opened it for me.

Comment: Okay, I see. This works in Unity. However it doesn't work in Gnome Shell, which I am running. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ahh, I thought the same would apply.